# How to auto open apps when closed?

Tags: windows, cmd

I have an application issues. It worked normally for a minutes, and after that its just closed for no reason. Im trying to change compability but it fix nothing.

Maybe there's some third-party apps that will help? Or just making a cmd commands?

Thanks!

Comment: What? Which application? Which OS? Any error messages or event log entries? Please ask a complete question. Btw.: you certainly don't want a script that just automatically restarts closing applications.

Comment: @ChrisTophski MinerGate (BTC mining app). Windows 10. I just checked the log file and its say "Tracker error: 3". Before this error I saw tracker error too, but the app didn't automaticly close